# How to move a specific dataframe row to the beginning of a subgroup and repeat for multiple subgroups

Tags: python

I have the dataframe below and I'm able to move a row with group_member_id=0 to the top with the script below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
'row_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
'group_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
'group_member_id':[1,0,2,3,1,2,0,3,3,2,1,0]
}

trips_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

    row_id  group_id  group_member_id
11      12         3                0
0        1         1                1
1        2         1                0
2        3         1                2
3        4         1                3
4        5         2                1
5        6         2                2
6        7         2                0
7        8         2                3
8        9         3                3
9       10         3                2
10      11         3                1
11      12         3                0
```

#Function to move one row with group_member_id =0 to the top
def shift_row_to_top(df):

```
#Shift row, given by index_to_shift, to top of df    
idx = df.index.tolist()  
index_to_shift = trips_data[trips_data['group_member_id']==0].index.values.max()
df = df.reindex([index_to_shift] + idx)

return df
```

The above code successfully moves just one row to the top (where group_member_id=0) but what I really want to do is; for each group of group_id (each group_id has four rows), I want to move group_member_id=0 to the top and leave the rest as it.

I tried the code below but got an error stating "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index":

```
def shift_row_to_top2(trips):
    print(trips)
    #Identify row index where group_member_id=0
    index_to_shift=trips[trips['group_member_id']==0].index.values
    idx = trips.index.tolist()
    idx.pop(index_to_shift)
    trips = trips.reindex([index_to_shift] + idx)


trips_data_all_shifted = trips_data.groupby(["group_id"]).apply(shift_row_to_top2)
```

Below is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve; first row of every group_id starts with group_member_id=0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# I was able to get to the solution
            
#Dataframe
            
data = {
        'row_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
        'group_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
        'group_member_id':[1,0,2,3,1,2,0,3,3,2,1,0]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            
#Function to move line of dataframe where 
#group_member_id==0 for each group of "group_id"
        
def shift_row_to_top(df):
    index_to_shift = df[df['group_member_id']==0].index.values.max()
    idx = [i for i in df.index if i!=index_to_shift]
    df2 = df.loc[[index_to_shift] + idx]
            
    return df2
            
    
df3 = df.groupby(["group_id"]).apply(shift_row_to_top)
    
print(df3)
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).